# Why are indexedDB requests made before the event handlers are declared?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

It feels like this must be a stupid question but I don't understand something fundamental about making a request in indexedDB.

Why are the requests made before the event handlers are defined?  For example, the `request = objectStore.add(data)` is made before the `request.onsuccess` and `request.onerror` functions are declared. Is this correct? Is it possible that the request could complete before the event handlers are registered?

I'm comparing it to the creation of an image element, followed by declaring the event handlers for onload and onerror, all before setting the source attribute to the location of a file and attempting to load it. But a request "element" can't be created before a request is made; so, there's nothing to attach the events to until the request has already been made.

Please let me know what I'm missing here. I've been writing and retrieving data from indexedDB without issue, and think I've been coding it correctly; but I want to make sure this is right and will always work.

Thank you.

**Duplicate Response**

I read that question and answer sometime ago, when I first started reading about indexedDB, and completely forgot about it.  Had I found it again before I wrote this question, I likely would not have submitted it and would've just accepted that the code ought to work out whether I understand it or not. Handling error events and transaction aborts is what got me to thinking about the statement order again.

However, after reading the answer again, I don't understand enough to be any further along than just accepting it and hoping it will always work.  I'm not trying to be snide.  In one sense, it is just confusing for my limited capacity to think of event loops and epochs and that everything sort of happens all at once.

> At the end of the epoch (or the start of the next, whatever you think is easier to understand), the underlying JS engine goes back and looks at what is registered to execute, and then executes everything nearly all at once.

There has to be an order of execution or nothing makes sense, asynchronous or not. I understand that the interpreter does not wait for an anysnchronous process to complete before starting to execute the next line of code. But aren't the synchronous statements processed completely in turn in the order they appear in the code and the asynchronous ones started off in the order they appear in the code, such that if an asynchronous process errored quickly, the event could be missed if the event handlers weren't declared in advance?  The event handlers are not hoisted like function declarations, are they?  This is the part that I still find confusing.

In this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) by Jake Archibald on promises, in the introduction he presents an example concerning the loading of images and writes:

> Unfortunately, in the example above, it's possible that the events happened before we started listening for them, so we need to work around that using the "complete" property of images.

and

> This doesn't catch images that error'd before we got a chance to listen for them; unfortunately the DOM doesn't give us a way to do that. Also, this is loading one image, things get even more complex if we want to know when a set of images have loaded.

That gives the impression that order is important, such that, in the case of images, when possible, the source should be assigned after declaring all the event handlers, in order to not miss hearing events.  The important part for me was the fact that an event could take place before the event handler was declared/registered.

I tried to follow the same pattern of making the request after declaring the event handlers in indexedDB, but it doesn't appear possible because there's nothing to attach the events to until the request is made.

Even when all the statements are asynchronous, such as in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) example in the MDN Web Docs on Using IndexedDB, some things are still rather confusing. The `objectStore.transaction.oncomplete` is an interesting statement.  We're waiting for the objectStore to be created before attempting to write data to it. (I think that's considered bad practice, writing data in an onupgradeneeded event; so, we don't use that statement.)  But what is confusing is why we don't worry about the objectStore being created before creating an index in it. Why isn't the createIndex statement started at the same time the createObjectStore statement started, if everything is processed all at once?  If the createObjectStore statement doesn't complete before the createIndex statement begins, shouldn't an event handler be required or it would fail because objectStore wouldn't yet exist?

I know it works because I've been using the same code pattern, but I really don't understand it.

These two items--the potential to miss events and why an event handler isn't needed in this indexedDB example--are what I'd like to better understand.  I don't know if this makes my question different or not, but the answer to the duplicate question doesn't answer these for me.  Perhaps, I'd have to understand the JS engine better to understand the answer to these questions.

```
const dbName = "the_name";

var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 2);

request.onerror = function(event) {
  // Handle errors.
};
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;

  // Create an objectStore to hold information about our customers. We're
  // going to use "ssn" as our key path because it's guaranteed to be
  // unique - or at least that's what I was told during the kickoff meeting.
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers", { keyPath: "ssn" });

  // Create an index to search customers by name. We may have duplicates
  // so we can't use a unique index.
  objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });

  // Create an index to search customers by email. We want to ensure that
  // no two customers have the same email, so use a unique index.
  objectStore.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });

  // Use transaction oncomplete to make sure the objectStore creation is 
  // finished before adding data into it.
  objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
    // Store values in the newly created objectStore.
    var customerObjectStore = db.transaction("customers", "readwrite").objectStore("customers");
    customerData.forEach(function(customer) {
      customerObjectStore.add(customer);
    });
  };
};
```

**Clarification/Response to Answer/Comments**

Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question and for the added explanation.

First, by "before" I simply mean the order in which the statements appear in the script.

I think I follow your analogy and it is a good one. I'm just still not clear on why the employees never submit their work to the secretary until the next day, when it is guaranteed that a secretary will be there to receive it.

It sounds similar to the fact that the javascript interpreter, when it performs its equivalent of compiling the script, hoists the function declarations, such that a function can be invoked in the code before the function declaration has been made.

It would appear that your saying, restated in my simple terms, that the JS engine, at some point before final execution, assigns the event handlers (the secretaries) to be registered in an earlier epoch than the one in which the requests (the employees) that utlimately trigger the events will complete. Therefore, it doesn't matter where in the code the request statements appear relative to the event handlers, that is, as long as they are defined within the same epoch.

The JS engine doesn't know when the request will complete, but only when the event handlers have been registered to start listening and when the request has commenced.  As long as the JS engine has a process to order these steps properly independent of the order the statements appear in the code, such that an event cannot be missed, then it's no different to me than the hoisting of function declarations and I don't really have to think much about it any longer to accomplish my tasks.

However, I would still like to better understand what an epoch is, at least in terms of knowing that the statements are made within the same epoch.  I don't see any mention of an epoch in the article on "Concurrecny Model and Event Loop" in MDN Web Docs. Would you mind pointing me to any good resources you know of?

Thank you.

**Final Notes**

I came across these two items through a link, here, on stack overflow.  This same question was asked eight years ago and was answered about the same way but with different terminology; that is, instead of epochs, it was that javascript code will "run to completion" or has run-to-completion semantics.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226505/doubts-about-html5-indexeddb-async-api?rq=1) refers you to this [document](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/comparing-indexeddb-and-webdatabase/#comment-92830) which can be searched for "run to completion" to read two exchanges about why there is not a race condition in this set up of making a request before registering the event handlers. The older JavaScript book I have by David Flanagan, in discussing the execution of JS "programs," states that, because JS has single-threaded execution, one never has to worry about race conditions; but I don't know if he was referring to this situation exactly.

Thus, this question has been asked and answered multiple times in the past and I guess I'm just another newbie asking an old question as if I was the first to have thought of it, and without enough knowledge of how JS processes.

The article "Concurrency Model and Event Loop", linked above, has a brief "Run-to-completion" section; but I didn't understand its implications until after reading the last document linked above.

I now take it to mean that all the code in a function will run to completion before any other code can begin, which seems to have two interpretations.

1. One is that the asynchronous request on the database is queued when the statement is reached in the function code but won't actually commence until all the other statements in the function are run, including the event handlers that are declared afterward.
2. Or, according to that last linked document above, the asynchronous request may run and even complete before the event handlers are registered, but the notification of its completion will remain in the queue and won't execute until after the rest of the statements in the function are run and the event handlers have been registered.

Interpretation 2 appears to be the accurate one but, whichever is the actual case, it all makes adequate sense to me now and explains why the secretary will always be there before the employee submits the work, and why, even if the employee finishes the work in a nanosecond, the employee won't submit the work until the next day when a secretary is guaranteed to be present to receive it. The employee may place the work-complete notification in the queue, but the queue won't sound the notification for a secretary to hear until the next day.

Thanks, Josh, for the additional explanation about what is meant by epochs and how that terminology works out in operation. I accepted your answer and appreciate you taking the time to write it all out.

Now that I seem to understand why the event-handler declarations can be made later in the code than the making of the request, I still don't understand why we can create an object store and then immediately create an index on that object store without having to wait until we know the object store has been successfully created, unless it is synchronous or something else special takes place in a versionchange transaction / onupgradeneeded event. There are no events mentioned in the MDN Web Docs description of createObjectStore and no examples that have any listeners on it; so; I'll just assume it's never necessary.

Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At which point is an IndexedDB request or transaction sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338471/at-which-point-is-an-indexeddb-request-or-transaction-sent)

Comment: I'm not sure what to add to my previous answers. Perhaps try and ask a narrower and clearer and particular question? I will be the first to admit that the leap from writing synchronous code to asynchronous code is really confusing.

Comment: In all fairness, the img example is an unfortunate one. Img onload should fire asynchronously too; i.e even if you do set the onload handler you did set its src, but still in a synchronous way, your event should fire. That is a bug in some implementations, probably because of the many ways this src can be set (e.g from the markup directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are the requests made before the event handlers are defined?

It does not matter.

> For example, the `request = objectStore.add(data)` is made before the request.onsuccess and request.onerror functions are declared. Is this correct?

Yes it is correct because again it does not matter.

I would be careful about your use of the word *before*. Maybe it means something different to me than it does to you. I can't tell. But maybe this is what is tripping you up.

> Is it possible that the request could complete before the event handlers are registered?

If you register the event handlers in the same epoch as when you make the request, then no. The request only completes in a later epoch.

---

Ok, here is my attempt at explaining by example (sorry if this is bad!). Personification is generally a good educational technique, and is less intimidating then using raw technical terms, so let's go with that.

Let's say you are a boss, and have employees. Let's say you ask an employee to do some work for you. Then, you ask that employee to report back to your secretary when they completed the work. Immediately after asking the employee to go do that other work, you carry on doing your own work, without waiting for that employee to finish their work and report back. You are both basically doing work at the same time.

Now, in this situation, what happens if you don't have a secretary at the time you hand the employee a request to do something? Well, no problem. You go and hire another secretary before that employee finishes their work and before that employee even knows who to report back to, which is fine because all the employee knows is they report to your secretary. The employee does not know whether your secretary exists or not at the time of being assigned work, and does not need to know that. The missing secretary did not prevent that employee from getting started, or understanding the work to be done. And by the time that employee completes their work, you have a secretary ready and waiting. Or, you don't, because you don't happen to care to even acknowledge whether the work was actually completed, you just made a command and trusted the employee to do their job, whatever. You really only care about having them report back to your secretary if you need to do some other work that has to wait until after the first project is done, and that is a different concern.

Let's pretend you already had a secretary at the time you assigned the employee the work. What is the difference between this situation of already having a secretary, and the situation where you go and hire one shortly after assigning the work, but before it is done? There is NO difference.

Now, let's try and really address your concern. What you're suggesting is that it seems impossible to reliably go out and hire that secretary before you know whether the employee finished their assignment. This I think is the critical misunderstanding. It is entirely possible to do this. Why is that? I suppose it is not the easiest thing to grasp.

I am going to stretch this metaphor a bit and impose a strange rule. No matter how simple the project you hand off to the employee, even if it is just to run and get you coffee in the morning, they will never ever get back to you the same day. They will always finish their work some later day, at the earliest tomorrow. They might even finish their work within one fleeting nanosecond of you telling them, but they will NEVER get back to you or your secretary right away, they will always be delayed until tomorrow at the earliest.

This means you have all day to go and hire that secretary that did not exist at the time you gave the employee the order. So long as you do it before tomorrow, you're good. That secretary will exist and be working for you by the time the employee responds tomorrow, and will be able to receive the message from the employee.

---

Edit response to your added comments:

Yep, hoisting is similar in many respects. Things can happen in a different order then written in code. Hoisting is of course synchronous so it is not a perfect similarity, but the out-of-order aspect is still similar.

Epoch is just my own word i use for a single iteration of the event loop. Like in the case of a for loop using i for i from 0 to 2, there are 3 epochs, iteration 0, iteration 1, and iteration 2. i just call them epochs because it is like categories of time.

In a promise case, it might even be a microtask. In a js worker case, it might be thread-like (and workers are the new hotness over the old child-iframe technique). Basically these are all just ways to 'realize' doing more than one thing at a time. Node calls it a tick, and has things like `nextTick()` that defers code execution until the next tick of its loop. Within a single epoch, things happen in the order they are written (and notably hoisting is all in epoch 0). but some code may be async, and therefore happen across epochs, and therefore may run in a different order than it was written. Code written earlier may happen in a later epoch.

When you make a request, it says, start doing this thing, and get back to me at the earliest in the next epoch. You have up until the end of the current epoch to register handlers for the request.

Some code, like in the case of an image preloader as mentioned in your example, has to take into account that it attaches the listeners too late (images are being preloaded in an alternate timeline and some may already be loaded and in some browsers this means load will not fire), so it wants to check imageElement.complete to catch that case. In other cases of event listener implementations, some dispatcher implementations will fire events to newly added listeners for events that already happened where the new listener was not listening at the time of the event. But that is not a universal characteristic of event listener implementations, just a characteristic of certain implementations.

And in the case of the transaction.oncomplete thing from within onupgradeneeded, that is just not a great example. It is doing stuff it does not need to do.

Comment: That's a very convoluted explanation, which IMM doesn't address OP's concerns. To extend the metaphor,  Your employee is not gonna wait anything. You have a basket of accomplished tasks. Your secretary must handle the content of this basket at the end of each day work. This way, it doesn't matter how fast your employee has been to handle the task, their result is waiting in the basket to be handled by the secretary. Nor does it matter if when the task has been given your secretary already knew how to handle these tasks, as long as they know before the end of the day work.

Comment: @JoshThank you for the explanation. I wrote a short response at the end of my question.

Comment: @KaiidoThank you for your comments. I didn't understand this one until just now. Is it accurate that your extension to the metaphor means that the asynchronous requests (the employees' tasks) may complete before the event handlers are registered (a secretary is hired), but the notifications will remain in the queue (the basket of accomplished tasks) and won't execute (notify the secretary) until after the event handlers are registered and the function runs to completion (the end of the work day)?

Comment: @Gary glad I helped

Comment: @Gary yes, it is possible, assuming that the asynchronous task is entirely performed by an other process than the js one. Here is an example using a web worker: https://jsfiddle.net/xg08cjys/

Comment: @KaiidoThank you for taking the time to put this interesting example together.

Comment: @Gary createObjectStore is synchronous

Answer (score 3):

This is the technical answer to your question:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops

The JS concurrency model is cooperative with "run-to-completion" semantics (no parallel processing of events in the same queue). This means that any async response will be posted as a message to the window event loop, and all the sequential code you see after the request is guaranteed to execute before the async response processing starts.

That said, from usability point of view, the IndexDB API is not affording the intent in the most expressive manner, and coming from other languages with preemptive threading you are excused for being confused :-)